# Elastic Search mapping bad mapping

Tags: json, mapping, elasticsearch

I have the following mapping for a Elastic Search index. I am posting ("PUT") it to http://abc.com/test/article/_mapping.

```
{
    "article": {
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "stem": {
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "standard",
                            "lowercase",
                            "stop",
                            "porter_stem"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "DocumentID": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "ContentSource": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "ContentType": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "PageTitle": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "stem"
                },
                "ContentBody": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "stem"
                },
                "URL": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an OK message from Elastic Search. But when I go to http://abc.com/test/article/_mapping , I don't see the settings of the mapping. All I see is this

```
{  "article" : {   "properties" : {   }  }}
```

I had this working before I added the settings portion for the analyzer. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The first "article" string needs to be deleted. And the "PUT" should happen against http://abc.com/index